# XAML/C# - Binding Property does not get called

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

Not sure why it does this...

I'm simplifying my problem for the sake of clarity. I have two variables that participate in data-binding. One variable is fetched fine, but the other one does not get fetched.

Example.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class Example : UserControl
{
    private string _name;
    private string _area;
    private AppClass _app;

    public Example(string name, AppClass app)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _name = name;
        _app = app;
        this.DataContext = this;
        InitializeData();
    }

    private void InitializeData()
    {
        if (_app != null)
        {
            _area = _app.GetArea();
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    public string Area
    {
        get { return _area; }
        set { _area = value; }
    }
}
```

And my Example.xaml (just the lines of interest):

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row='0' Grid.Column ='0' Padding='5,0,0,0' Background='LightBlue' Text='Exchanger'/>
<TextBlock Grid.Row='0' Grid.Column ='1' Background='LightBlue' Text="{Binding Name}" TextAlignment='Center'/>

<TextBlock Grid.Row='2' Grid.Column ='0' Padding='5,0,0,0' Background='LightCyan' Text='Area'/>
<TextBlock Grid.Row='2' Grid.Column ='1' Background='LightCyan' Text="{Binding Area}" TextAlignment='Center'/>
```

Interestingly enough, `Area` gets called fine, but `Name` doesn't. I put a breakpoint on the getter of `Name` and `Area` and it breaks on `Area` but not `Name`. I'm perplexed...

Comment: WPF? WinRT? Silverlight?

Comment: I can see you doing something with `_area` in `InitializeData()` but not with `_name`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `Name` property is defined in `FrameworkElement`. Change the property name to something else.

Also, The UI is not the right place to store your data. Instead of doing that, create a proper ViewModel to hold your data and make sure your usercontrol is bound to that ViewModel.

Comment: Woops, I need to be better at naming....Thanks, that fixed it. Thanks for MVVM suggestion, will eventually migrate to that as well. Cheers.